# How to get max and min values of an Array of Tuples

Tags: scala, tuples

Say I have a List of Tuples of Integers

```
var i = Array(1->3, 5->9, 15->18)
```

How can I return a Tuple of the highest and lowest values from the above?

So for the above input, 1-> 18 should be returned as 1 is the lowest and 18 is the highest value. Here's the skeleton of the function that takes an Array of Tuples and returns the highest & the lowest values as a Tuple.

```
    def returnHighest(i: Array[(Int, Int)]): (Int, Int)={

      ....

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of ways to do this of course. Here is one:

```
val i = Array(1->3, 5->9, 15->18)
i: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,3), (5,9), (15,18))

scala> val flatI = i.flatMap{case(a,b) => List(a, b)}
flatI: Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 18)

scala> flatI.min -> flatI.max
res3: (Int, Int) = (1,18)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use foldLeft, but you need to be careful about the start value. What if the array is empty ?

```
val res4 = Array(1->3, 5->9, 15->18)
res4.foldLeft(res4(0))({
    case (acc, i) =>
      Math.min(acc._1, i._1) -> Math.max(acc._2, i._2)
  }) 
res6: (Int, Int) = (1, 18)
```

Comment: Since order doesn't matter, and you're failing on an empty list anyway, you can just use `res4.reduce { (t1, t2) => (Math.min(t1._1, t2._1), Math.max(t1._2, t2._2)) }`.